# Removing Information

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, wildcards

I have information in an Excel column I'm trying to remove. The cell contains MMM DD HH:MM:SS YYYY. I just want to remove the HH:MM:SS from the cell and leave the rest in there. I tried copying and pasting the column into Notepad ++ and trying to find a way to use the Find and replace option to remove that part of the data. Since each cell contains a different time how can I have that part of the information removed? I was hoping I could use wildcards but that doesn't seem to work. I tried in the Replace function Find what: **:**:** but its not working. Is there a way to do what I'm looking to do efficiently? I'd just hate to go line by line to hand jam it. Thank you

Comment: I guess you need [Regular Expressions](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Is the date cell in actual Date format or in General/Text? Also, is every date exactly 20 characters long? If so, you can just use Excel functions to grab the desired substring of each cell.

Comment: Can't you just change the cell format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Notepad++, you can do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\d\d:\d\d:\d\d`   # there is a space in front of expression and after it
- Replace with:      # a space
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
        # a space
\d\d    # 2 digits
:       # a colon
\d\d    # 2 digits
:       # a colon
\d\d    # 2 digits
        # a space
```

Comment: Toto you are a genious if no one has yet told you today. Thank you. Saved me lots of working hours.

Comment: @Ben - if that answer worked for you, then please mark it as correct

Comment: @Ben: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: This works and is obviously what OP was looking for (so kudos, Toto), but for posterity: this is a very cringy hack and is totally ignoring the awesome power of Excel itself :( If anyone needs to do this sort of thing in the future, please don't use NPP as your first resort.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just reformat the column.
[image]